# error to install composer because of php file

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

Greeting developers, I want to learn laravel framework for my project. For that i follow some instruction in google to install it . i should have composer to install it. i try to download composer but there have some errors.the error is:

```
The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly:

C:\xampp\php\php.exe

The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: 

C:\xampp\php\php.ini

A setting in your php.ini could be causing the problem: Either the 'extension_dir' value is incorrect or the dll does not exist.

Program Output:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_mysql.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mysql.dll (The specified module could not be found.
), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_mysql.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.
)) in Unknown on line 0
```

i try to resolve it. i check the php.ini file all looking good only. Is that because of i am using xampp server 7.2.0. I am really need a solution.

Comment: You need to install the `php_mysql` extension. Your php binary was not compiled with it.

Comment: I would say the opposite, you need to remove it (comment it out with `;php_mysql.dll`) from the php.ini. Because its been deprecated and "removed" in PHP7.  Also just looking at what you posted `C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_mysql.dll.dll`  `php_php_mysql.dll.dll` ? seems weird.  Double you fun, 2 `php_` and `dll` extensions... lol

Comment: You should consider using Homestead, which provides a more stable locale dev environment - especially if you are developing on Windows: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/homestead

Answer (score 0):

Turning the comment by ArtisticPhoenix into an answer.:

> I would say the opposite, you need to remove it (comment it out with  `;php_mysql.dll`) from the php.ini. Because its been deprecated and "removed" in PHP7. Also just looking at what you posted `C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_mysql.dll.dll php_php_mysql.dll.dll` ? seems weird. Double you fun, 2 `php_` and `dll` extensions... lol

ArtisticPhoenix Sep 29 '18 at 7:54

I tested it successful.

Comment: Can you add a quote around the comment, so it's obvious where it came from, please?

Comment: Turning a helpful comment into an answer after testing it makes sense. Please [edit] to filter the non-answering parts away please. Also consider asking @ArtisticPhoenix , or at least notify of your use. (Copying something into an answer for the purpose of saying "Thanks" is however not considered an answer....)